# Как установить mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Это требуется для установки *HostCMS*.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще странно, что за полгода так и не ответили.
Для тех кому интересно рецепт для Debian/Ubuntu
ставим апач:

```
 # apt-get install apache2
```

включаем нужный модуль:

```
   # a2enmod rewrite
```

проверяем:

```
   # apache2ctl -M | grep "rewrite_module"
```

Есть второй способ, длиннее. См. ссылку http://nixtalks.com/enable_mod_rewrite